# Meaning of $\mathbb{R}^E$ in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I'm reading through [Lovasz's paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2004/0009/0001/SDG-2004-0009-0001-a007.pdf) 
on discrete analytic functions but I'm confused about how the coboundary of a node $\delta v$ is defined. What does $\mathbb{R}^E$ mean on page 243 where $E$ is the set of edges of a graph. Later in the paper I see $\mathbb{R}^V$ as well where $V$ is the vertex set.

I tried looking up what $\mathbb{R}$ to the power of a set could mean but found no results.

Comment: Given two sets $X,Y$, the set of functions $X \to Y$ is often notated by $Y^X$ (notice the order). This is sensible, as a point $v \in Y^X$ has $X$-indexed coordinates, each coordinate taking values in $Y$. This is precisely the data of a function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: If you want to type your comment as an answer I can accept it.